# Data Source Binding in JBoss

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, jboss

How can i configure default data source of j boss for data base connection and database fail over. How can i get connection to my java class from that data source. Am using hibernate and my database in Mysql.

Comment: What version of jboss are you running?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should find everything you need at this [documentation for datasources](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/ConfigDataSources)